# IcCube - Treemap with Parent/Child dimension

Tags: parent-child, treemap, iccube

I currently try to build a google treemap chart in IcCube. Do I do this using a Multi Level dimension and defining every Level of drilldown separately (as shown 
[here](http://www.iccube.com/forums/topic/treemap-charts/) and [here](http://www.iccube.com/forums/topic/handling-related-treemap-charts/)), everything works fine. 
What I would like to do is using a Parent/Child dimension and telling the treemap, just to go down this hierarchy when drilling into the treemap chart.

Is that possible?

Here is the (not working) MDX I used, where [categories] is the Parent/Child dimension:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [category_name] as [categories].[categories].currentmember.name 
SELECT
  {[category_name],[Measures].[count_clicks]} on 0,
  non empty [categories].[categories] on 1
FROM
  [Cube]
```

Answer (score 1):

Treemap is a tricky visualization. You need to define the two first columns as defining the parent/child relation. For example :

```
'Global',    null 
'America',   'Global' 
'Europe',    'Global'
'Brazil',    'America'
```

The first column is by construction the Axis(1) name, so the seconds has to be the name of the parent and not the name of the member. Something like :

```
MEMBER [parent_name] as IIF( [categories].[categories].currentmember is [categories].[categories].[ALL],
                            NULL,
                            [categories].[categories].currentmember.parent.name )
```

That you can use as :

```
WITH
  MEMBER [parent_name] as IIF( [categories].[categories].currentmember is [categories].[categories].[ALL],NULL,[categories].categories].currentmember.parent.name )
SELECT
  {[parent_name],[Measures].[count_clicks]} on 0,
  non empty [categories].[categories] on 1
FROM
  [Cube]
```

This should work better.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a while with my own data, I took the IcCube example of the parent/child Dimension (http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_parentchild.php). Then I tried your example:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [parent_name] as IIF( [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].currentmember 
  is  [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].[ALL],'',
  [dim (ALL)]. [Hierarchy].currentmember.parent.name )
SELECT
  {[parent_name],[Measures].[value]} on 0,
  non empty [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy] on 1
FROM
  [Cube]
```

(The NULL value had to be replaced by '')

The first dimension works, but if I try to drill into the map, the system tells me, that there is no row with id 'World'. Do you have any ideas, how to fix that?

EDIT:
After using real names in the parent/child dimension instead of ids (child: Spain; parent: Europe, value: 3) and replacing  [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy] with  [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].members() in the code, I got a treemap working so far:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [parent_name] as IIF( [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].currentmember 
  is [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy],'',
  [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent.name )
SELECT
  {[parent_name],[Measures].[value]} on 0,
  non empty [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].members() on 1
FROM
  [Cube]
```

Now after drilling down to the next level, the is an error message 'failed to find row with id "Europe"'. And I added a 3 Level into my data (child: Madrid; parent: Spain, value: 5), but I am unable to go to this level. Clicking on "Spain" doesn't change anything.